# Data Persistence openFileOutput and openFileInput

Tags: android

I am trying to get my rss reader to save the URL address so when it is reopened it will save it. But for same reason the openFileOutput, and openFileInput is in red and it says that it can not resolve method.

Our professor had us watch a video online and I wrote it the same as his and his was working. his video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlIHJNCKpkw

```
 private void saveArticles(){

        try{
                                       //is in red cannot resolve method
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(urlAddress.getText().toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());

        }
    }

        private String getSavedArticles(){
            String contexts = "";

            try{
                                     //is in red cannot resolve method
                FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(FILENAME);
                int c ;

                while((c = fin.read()) != -1){
                    contexts = contexts + (char)c;
                }
                fin.close();
                return contexts;
            }

            catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());
            }

            return "";

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

openFileInput and openFileOutput are members of the Context class.  Activity inherits from Context, so you can use these methods inside your Activity class.  Otherwise, you'll need to pass that Activity (or Context) to the other class.

Pass your Activity instance to the class that implements saveArticles.

```
private void saveArticles(Context context)
{
    ...
     FileInputStream fit = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
}
```